# Problema al obtener resultados de una función con Loop

Tags: javascript

Estoy practicando JS, haciendo pruebas y hice el siguiente código. Consiste en hacer **cálculos de las propinas a pagar** según la cantidad total de la cuenta.

Para ello creo **dos objetos iguales** (**var john** y **var mark**), cada uno con un **array de "cuentas"** y un **condicional de "porcentajes"** a pagar según el precio de la "cuenta".

```js
var john = {
  fullName: 'John Smith',
  bills: [124, 48, 268, 180, 42],
  tipsCalc: function () {
    this.tips = [];
    this.finalValues = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < this.bills.length; i++) {


      // Determinate percentage based on tipping rules
      var percentage;


      if (this.bills[i] < 50) {
        percentage = .2;

      } else if (this.bills[i] >= 50 && this.bills[i] < 200) {
        percentage = .15;

      } else {
        percentage = .1;

      }

      // Add results to the corresponing arrays

      this.tips[i] = this.bills[i] * percentage;
      this.finalValues[i] = this.bills[i] + this.bills[i] * percentage;
    }
  }
}


john.tipsCalc();
console.log('John\'s Family TIPS ' + john.tips);
console.log('John\'s Family BILLS ' + john.bills);
console.log('John\'s Family Final a pagar ' + john.finalValues);

console.log('---------------------------------------------------');

var mark = {
 fullName: 'Mark Miller',
 bills: [77, 475, 110, 45],
 tipsCalc: function () {

  this.tips = [];
  this.finalValues = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < this.bills.length; i++) {
   // Determinate percentage based on tipping rules
   var percentage;

   if (this.bills[i] < 100) {
    percentage = .2;

   } else if (this.bills[i] >= 100 && this.bills[i] < 300) {
    percentage = .1;
   } else {
    percentage = .25;
   }

   // Add results to the corresponing arrays

   this.tips[i] = this.bills[i] * percentage;
   this.finalValues[i] = this.bills[i] + this.bills[i] * percentage;
  }
 }
}


mark.tipsCalc();
console.log('Mark\'s Family TIPS ' + mark.tips);
console.log('Mark\'s Family BILLS ' + mark.bills);
console.log('Mark\'s Family Final a pagar ' + mark.finalValues);
```

Posteriormente, he hecho una **función para calcular la suma** y el **promedio de las propinas de ambos "objetos"**. El caso es que el resultado primero "average(john)" me da correcto y el segundo "average(mark)" no, ya que me suma el anterior con ese mismo.

```
var sum = 0;
var averageTips;

function average(family) {

    for (let i = 0; i < family.tips.length; i++) {

        sum += family.tips[i];    
    }

    return averageTips = sum / (family.tips.length);
}

console.log('---------------------------------------------------');

average(john);
console.log('John\'s Family Suma TIPS = ' + sum);
console.log('John\'s Family Average TIPS = ' + averageTips);

console.log('---------------------------------------------------');

average(mark);
console.log('Mark\'s Family Suma TIPS = ' + sum);
console.log('Mark\'s Family Average TIPS = ' + averageTips);
```

No encuentro la forma de que me salga el último resultado (el de average(mark)) correcto. ¿Alguien me podría decir por qué?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sólo necesitas hacer locales las variables `sum` y `average` a la función `average` (realmente esta última no hace falta, como verás) y devolver ambas en un objeto:

```
function average(family) {
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < family.tips.length; i++) {
    sum += family.tips[i];    
  }
  return {
    sum,
    averageTips: sum / (family.tips.length)
  };
}

let dataMark = average(mark);
console.log('Mark\'s Family Suma TIPS = ', dataMark.sum);
console.log('Mark\'s Family Average TIPS =', dataMark.averageTips);
```

La opción fea pero sencilla sería inicializar la variable sum cada vez:

```
var sum = 0;
var averageTips;

function average(family) {
    sum = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < family.tips.length; i++) {

        sum += family.tips[i];    
    }

    return averageTips = sum / (family.tips.length);
}
```

Pero lo **desaconsejo**: es una buena práctica crear las variables lo más locales posible.

Comment: Justo lo que necesitaba Pablo, muchas gracias por tu ayuda, solucioné el problema! Un saludo